# How to draw outline in selected tableviewcell in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to outline Uitableview's selected cell

can anyone tell me how to do this ?

searched but nothing worked till now :(

should I do anything in rowdidselect method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property on the UITableView to YES - the default is NO

[For More](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1516322?start=0&tstart=0)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

What I understand from your question is u want to change the look off the selected cell...
On didSelectRowAtIndexPath Event you have the index off that row by that index draw a New CELL off your desire.

Comment: hmmm.. somewhat .. exactly I want to draw outline for the selected cell so that user can see that which cell has been selected

Comment: But I am not getting what you are trying to say :( ... can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom uiview and override the drawrect method so that it will create border lines across the given rect. Add this view to the cell.contentview when didSelectrow method is getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subclass your UITableViewCell. Then in the drawRect method you can draw that.

```
- (void) drawRect : (CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect]; 
    if (self.selected)
    {
      // put one image as outline  
    } 
}
```

I hope this might help you.
Naveen